# How can I get transparentAtStart parameter working in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to embed a video in my aspx page. Everything works fine. The video is not started immediately by setting `autostart=false`.

Now I want to show a fixed initial image in place of black screen. In IE I did it by setting `transparentAtStart=true` and some JavaScript code. I was hoping to do the same in Firefox and Chrome, but both don't seem to understand `transparentAtStart` tag.

I am playing a .wmv file using a .mwv plugin. Is there any other way to show fixed initial image before the user clicks play?

Comment: This is html 5 video or is my answer irrelevant here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML 5 video poster attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_video_poster.asp) for your image.

```
<video poster="/images/poster.jpg" autostart="false">
    <!-- sources -->
</video>
```